# 'lazy symbol binding failed' error when attempting to install gem bundler

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby, rubygems

***Question***

I'm trying to install MetaSploit on my iPhone 5S with iOS 8.1.3. Pangu Jailbreak. I've run into an issue with getting it working. Whenever I run the command `ruby msfconsole` I get a dependency error

```
iphone:/msf3 root# ruby msfconsole
[*] Metasploit requires the Bundler gem to be installed
    $ gem install bundler
```

So then I attempt to install the bundler as instructed, but then I encounter the error.

```
iphone:/msf3 root# gem install bundler
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __OSSwapInt16
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-darwin9/socket.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __OSSwapInt16
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-darwin9/socket.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

does anyone know how to fix this?

***gem environment***

```
iphone:/msf3 root# gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [arm-darwin9]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - arm-darwin-9
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /var/root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

***Gemfile***

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Add default group gems to `metasploit-framework.gemspec`:
#   spec.add_runtime_dependency '<name>', [<version requirements>]
gemspec name: 'metasploit-framework'

# separate from test as simplecov is not run on travis-ci
group :coverage do
  # code coverage for tests
  # any version newer than 0.5.4 gives an Encoding error when trying to read the source files.
  # see: https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/127 (hopefully fixed in 0.8.0)
  gem 'simplecov'
end

group :development do
  # Markdown formatting for yard
  gem 'redcarpet'
  # generating documentation
  gem 'yard'
  # for development and testing purposes
  gem 'pry'
end

group :development, :test do
  # automatically include factories from spec/factories
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
  # Make rspec output shorter and more useful
  gem 'fivemat', '~> 1.3.1'
  # running documentation generation tasks and rspec tasks
  gem 'rake', '>= 10.0.0'
  # Define `rake spec`.  Must be in development AND test so that its available by default as a rake test when the
  # environment is development
  gem 'rspec-rails' , '~> 3.3'
end

group :test do
  # cucumber extension for testing command line applications, like msfconsole
  gem 'aruba'
  # cucumber + automatic database cleaning with database_cleaner
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  # Manipulate Time.now in specs
  gem 'timecop'
end
```